# GLPaint in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, opengl-es-2.0

Do anyone tried GLPaint sample application with OpenGl ES 2.0 ? I had a try an got errors with  `glMatrixMode(), glPointSize(), glOrthof(), glTexEnvf()` methods .

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of those errors are because the code uses functions and constants that were **removed** in OpenGL ES 2.0.  If you want to make that app use OpenGL ES 2.0, you will have to replace those calls with code that uses OpenGL ES 2.0 functions only.

There are significant differences between OpenGL ES 1.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0.  Porting an app from 1.1 to 2.0 is not trivial.  You will need to learn quite a bit about both OpenGL ES 1.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0 to port the app.

For the specific functions you mentioned:

`glMatrixMode` and `glOrthof` have no replacements in OpenGL ES 2.0.  You are expected to provide your own vector/matrix math code.  If you are targeting iOS 5.0, you will want to look at the `GLKMath` part of the `GLKit` framework.

`glPointSize` is replaced by the `gl_PointSize` variable in the vertex shader.

`glTexEnvf` is replaced by vertex and fragment shaders.