# Set point size in LibGdx when using GL20

Tags: libgdx

I need to render some points with specified size using ShapeRenderer.

When using GL20, Gdx.gl and Gdx.gl20 will be initialized, while Gdx.gl10 and Gdx.gl11 will be null.

I can set line width and render using code such as this:

```
Gdx.gl.glLineWidth(5);
mShapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Rectangle);
mShapeRenderer.rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
mShapeRenderer.end();
```

But, from what I figured out, I can only set point size using `Gdx.gl10.glPointSize(5)` or `Gdx.gl11.glPointSize(5)` - which won't work in my case since both gl10 and gl11 are null.

Are there any simple solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenGL ES dropped support for glPointSize (among other things) in 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426803/glpaint-in-opengl-es-2-0), that's why you can't find it in `Gdx.gl20`, or in `Gdx.gl`.

Instead of setting a point size, just use ShapeRenderer's filledCircle to render the "large" points.  (I would point to the API documentation, but they just changed the API last week and I'm not sure which version you are using.)